# ssh-keyscan with t option with rsa type for MacOS does not return the public key

Tags: windows-10, macos, ssh, openssh

Having the following:

- Windows 10 with Git's bash enabled in the console
- MacOS (el Capitan)

If is executed

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa 192.168.1.X
```

In both OS return the same data as expected, such as:

```
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
192.168.1.X ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 XxXxXxX...XxXxXxX
```

The command shown above was tested with 6 different PC in the same LAN. Until here all ok.
Furthermore, all work fine with the `ed25519` key type too, such as:

```
ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 192.168.1.X
```

But if the key type is changed to `rsa` as follows:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa 192.168.1.X
```

In Windows returns the same structure as the two previous keys - the **situation** is that in MacOS always only returns

```
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
```

As you can see only the "comment" but not the public key.

Why this behavior? is possible fix it or do some extra configuration?

**Note**

Without filters or not indicating the key type - no use of the `-t` option - therefore

```
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X
```

In Windows returns the 3 key types mentioned, but in MacOS only 2 (always nothing about `rsa`)

**Verbose**

With the execution:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa -v 192.168.1.X
```

The output is:

```
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
```

Comment: Does adding `-v` to your invocation of `ssh-keyscan` on the Mac give you any additional clues?

Comment: @Spiff, thanks for the reply, added the `Verbose` section